# How to run logic over several large apache log files in Python?

Tags: python, performance, loops, logging, temporary

I have a bunch of apache log files, which I need to parse and extract information from. My script is working fine for a single file, but I'm wondering on the best approach to handle multiple files.

Should I:

```
- loop through all files and create a temporary file holding all contents
- run my logic on the "contact-ed" file
```

Or

```
- loop through every file
- run my logic file by file
- try to merge the results of every file
```

Filewise I'm looking at logs of about a year, with roughly 2 million entries per day, reported for a large number of machines. My single-file script is generating an object with "entries" for every machine, so I'm wondering:

**Question:**
Should I generate a joint temporary file or run file-by-file, generate file-based-objects and merge x files with entries for the same y machines?

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf. This is what I learned generators from and he has some cool examples for large log files

Comment: @javex: also interesting! I'm having a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `glob` and the `fileinput` module to effectively loop over all of them and see it as one "large file":

```
import fileinput
from glob import glob

log_files = glob('/some/dir/with/logs/*.log')
for line in fileinput.input(log_files):
    pass # do something
```

Comment: @frequent If the files need to be processed in some strict order, then you may wish to consider sorting `log_files` on some criteria...